# API Twillio: How to check Twilio call duration

Tags: twilio

I'm working with Twillio API to make outbound calls to my customers, but I want to have more information about the status of the call.

Is there a way to check the call duration and status by using any API from Twillio?

I need to check which calls were not done or calls with less than 10 seconds of duration in order to re send them again.

I would like to receive a JSON data format with the status of the call

Comment: Hi, please add a little more info about your project to let other people understand how they can help you. A good idea would be to read [how to ask good questions on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to do this is to use a [Voice Webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-overview) that triggers at the end of the call. Here is a code sample from the [Twilio Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#ending-the-call-callback-requests):

```
var response = new VoiceResponse();
        var dial = new Dial();
        dial.Number("+12349013030", statusCallbackEvent: new []{Number
            .EventEnum.Initiated, Number.EventEnum.Ringing, Number.EventEnum
            .Answered, Number.EventEnum.Completed}.ToList(),
            statusCallback: new Uri("https://myapp.com/calls/events"),
            statusCallbackMethod: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Post);
        response.Append(dial);

        Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
```

When the call ends, your https://myapp.com/calls/events endpoint will receive a webhook that includes the Call Duration - The duration in seconds of the just-completed call. Your application will store this information and then you can run reports or queries off your stored data.

The non-recommended way to to loop through the Twilio Logs and check the duration for each call as there is no way to filter the Twilio Logs by call duration.